# Formik MaterialUI input masking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a form in formik and fields generally look like that:

```html
<Field
          component={TextField}
          name="phoneNumber"
          type="text"
          required
          label={t('containers:CommonFields.phoneNumber')}
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
/>
```

Where Field is imported from Formik and TextField is just styled [formik-material-ui](https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui) textfield:

```
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui';
import breakpoints from 'styles/breakpoints';
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';

export default styled(TextField)`
  ${breakpoints.md`
    max-width: 320px;
  `};
  width: 100%;
`;
```

What i want to do is add input mask to that field using [react-input-mask](https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask). This is what I've got so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-currying-hryv1

Unfortunately the input is not rendering

Answer (score 3):

Change your `TextField` import to

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
```

[updated sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-banach-lsn9e)

or, if you want to keep [formik textfield](https://stackworx.github.io/formik-material-ui/docs/api/material-ui#textfield) then check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-platform-hqh1c)

Comment: That is working partially - the form is not 'seeing' the value of the input in both cases. Console is not logging anything

Comment: @n3stle check this https://codesandbox.io/s/248vzprz2p?file=/index.js

Answer (score 2):

You need to change a couple of things inside your FormikTextField component.

1. You don't need a local state, your input should be controlled by Formik.
2. You need to pass the props that Formik Field sends its children into InputMask.
3. You need to pass input props to children inside InputMask.

In the end, the working component should look something like

```
const FormikTextField = (props) => {
  return (
    <InputMask
      {...props}
      {...props.field}
      mask="(0)999 999 99 99"
      disabled={false}
      maskChar=" "
    >
      {(inputProps) => <StyledTextField {...inputProps} />}
    </InputMask>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [working version](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-mask-38466). I think we need to use `useField` hook provided by `formik` and use the component directly inside the `formik` form, not as component prop.

Comment: It works fine in normal ime, but if user is using composition IME (Chinese/Japanese and etc). All input will be duplicated. Any ideas to solve this issue?